# How to create and read a simple .txt File

Tags: java, file

I am a newbee and I need help to include some Highscores , so (because its just a little count of numbers )
I decided to do it with a .txt File .
So how can I create one and how to read it later ?

Comment: [This](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-io/file.html) and [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/java_io_file.htm) should get you started.

Comment: You can write with PrintWriter and read with Scanner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating and using files are both pretty easy to do with the `java.io` package that can be used with a simple `import java.io.*` statement at the top of your file.

After including the file, you will need to create an instance of the `File` variable type like such:

```
File newFile = new File ("fileName");
```

You can get lots of standard file information such as file size with just this instantiation. However, to write to the file you should create an instance of a `BufferedWriter`; this buffered writer will write all of the stuff you want to the file. You will need to pass a `new FileWriter` into your `BufferedWriter`, that will in turn take `File` object, for reasons I can explain if you really want to know:

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(newFile));
```

Now write anything to the file using the following:

```
writer.write ("stuff you want to write");
```

For reading, you open the file with the following statement:

```
FileReader fReader = new FileReader ("fileName");
BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader (fReader);
```

And then read from the file using

```
String text = bReader.readLine ();
```

You can find the specifics of all of these methods [in the official java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/package-summary.html).

**Note: You will need to surround your `BufferedWriter` declaration in a `try-catch` statement since it can throw an exception. I can write an example if you need me to**